# Filling the area between three curves in MatLab with Bold Plot

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I am trying to make a graph similar to the one below:

[image]

I have the plots for the lower bound of the graph, the median (bold line) and the upper bound. I tried working around with fill but it seems to create weird filled polygons. Also, how can I make the median plot bold?

Thanks.

Edit: Here is a MWE trying to plot such a graph for the curve y=1/x.

```
x=1:1:20
y1 = 1./x
y2 = 1./x-2
y3 = 1./x+2
fill(x,y2,'b',x,y1,'b',x,y3,'b')
```

Comment: see `patch` function, and `'LineWidth'` parameter of the `plot` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[shadedplot.m](http://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/18738-shaded-area-plot/content/shadedplot.m) works very nicely for applications like that.

Try this:

```
shadedplot(x, y2, y3, [0.8 0.8 1], [0.8 0.8 1])
hold on
plot(x, y1, 'Color', [0.3 0.3 0.8], 'Linewidth', 3)
```

[image]